# "Y" as a vowel in a name

Tags: vowels

Can the letter "y" be used to represent the "ee" sound in the middle of a name, like it is at the end of baby, lady or Lacy.

What I mean is, is it okay to spell Khaleesi as Khalysi etc.

Comment: Many Americans have a creative approach to spelling  where first names are concerned. I'd say go for it, but people will still ask how to pronounce and spell the name

Comment: Americans like to stick Y in the names of their baby girls.  Instead of Lidia they may write Lydia.  Instead of Carol they may write Caryl.  But the pronunciation stays the same as the original.

Comment: 1. Just about **anything** is okay with given names. 2. It may not be fair, though, to confound people about how to pronounce the name. @GEdgar Non-natives speakers may not pronounce "Lidia" and "Lydia" alike even if they are meant to be.

Comment: If the question is broadened to include **any word** in the English language, that would be very interesting (and more appropriate here on ELU).

Comment: /ˈsɪmɪtri/; /əˈbɪs/; /əˈsɛtɪliːn/; /kəˈlɪpsəʊ/; /krɪpt/; ...

Comment: 'Lydia' is the standard spelling, but the 'y' is pronounced like 'i' in 'pin' rather than 'ee'. (I would pronounce 'baby' and 'lady' like that too.)

Comment: Kate Bunting I appreciate your reply however in the International Phonetic Alphabet the word 'pin' is transcribed as 'pɪn' whilst the word 'baby' is transcribed as 'ˈbeɪbi'. The IPA 'ɪ' is pronounced as the 'i' (pin, hit etc.) whilst the IPA 'i' is pronounced as 'ee' (baby, green etc.). My question is are there any rules against representing the IPA 'i' with a 'y' in the middle of a name?

Comment: @DickBrown The y in _baby_ is most commonly nowadays written /ɨ/ (or as /ɪ/ with a crossbar, which I can’t write on my phone) precisely because its quality varies between speakers: some pronounce it /ɪ/ like in _pin_, others pronounce it /i/. Note that the latter is **not** the same sound as in _green_; that’s long /iː/. The _baby_ sound is short. For those that pronounce it /i/, it is a unique phone which doesn’t exist anywhere else in the language except word-finally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: In my experience, /ɨ/ is typically used to represent a vowel that can be /ɪ/ or /ə/ (as in the second syllable of *competent,* or the last syllable of *civil*) rather than a vowel that can be /iː/ or /ɪ/. And I don't think it's common to analyze /i/ (the "happy" vowel) as a unique phone. See my post on ELL SE: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/100787/18197

Comment: @sumelic You’re absolutely right, of course. I shouldn’t be posting at 7:30 in the morning; I’m clearly not awake at that time. It is fairly common, though, to write [i] for the _baby_ sound and [iː] for the _green_ sound, which does make them different phones. Like the /ɪ ə/ variation, this is an /ɪ i/ variation which I don’t think exists anywhere else.

Comment: Spelling *Khaleesi* as *Khalysi* seems pretty innocuous compared to spelling  *Fanshaw* as *Featherstonehaugh*, *Beecham* as *Beauchamp*, or *Cane* as *Kean*.

Answer (score 5):

There are no rules about whether it's "OK" to spell certain sounds certain ways in names. People would only be able to give you their opinions on the matter, not any kind of definitive answer.

If you use an unusual spelling, people will be more likely to mispronounce the name. When surrounded by consonant letters, the letter Y usually represents the sound /aɪ/ (as in *ps**y**chic*) or /ɪ/ (as in *ph**y**sics*), not /i/.

It's only usual for Y to represent /i/ in unstressed syllables, and when there is no following consonant letter (as in *lad**y*** or *kar**y**otype*). As  Kate Bunting mentioned in a comment, some British English speakers use the sound /ɪ/ instead in these contexts.

(Because of certain regional sound changes turning /ɪ/ into /i/ in certain other very specific contexts where these sounds do not contrast (either before /r/ or before /ŋ/), some American English speakers may also have /i/ instead of /ɪ/ in the word *l**y**ric,* and/or in the word *l**y**nx,* but neither of these is relevant to your example.)